# How to use forceseek scan in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012.

My queries are:

```
create table tab (id int, nm varchar(10))

insert into tab values (1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')

create index IX_nm on tab(id)
go

create table tab2(id1 int, age int)

insert into tab2 values (1, 21), (2, 22), (3, 54)

create index IX_nm2 on tab2(id1)
go

select * 
from tab a 
inner join tab2 b on a.id = b.id1

select * 
from tab a 
inner join tab2 b with(forceseek) on a.id = b.id1
```

I have included the execution plans of them.

[image]

[image]

I am not able to differentiate between the 2 queries, and they produce the same execution plan.

Comment: You used `FORCESEEK` ont tab2, not tab. But why do you want to do that anyway? You are asking for all columns from a very small number of rows. Using a SEEK would be slower than a scan in this case. Do you have a different query that you think doesn't perform well enough? In this case second-guessing the optimizer will make things worse, not better

Comment: *How to use forceseek scan* - what do you mean?? **Either** you use `FORCESEEK` to get an index seek (which you do get, as the execution plan shows) - or then you have (or want?) a `SCAN` which is a totally different operation... a "forceseek scan" doesn't make any sense.....

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between the two plans because SQL Server has already chosen to do an Index Seek on `tab2.IX_nm2` without the need for the `FORCESEEK` hint.

Take a look at the plan produced:

[image]

You want **all** rows from `tab`, so SQL Server does a table scan. It won't use `IX_nm` because it doesn't contain `nm` and would have to do a lookup to retrieve this column from the heap.  However, you could use a `CLUSTERED` index which will remove that table scan:

```
create CLUSTERED index IX_nm on tab(id);
```

The Nested Loop between The Scan and the Seek basically says, `For every row returned by the Table Scan on tab, get me the corresponding row from tab2 based on the ID`. The underlying statistics on `IX_nm2` indicates to SQL Server that there is likely to be only one or two rows returned and so it does a Seek for those rows, rather than scans the whole table.

However, because your index is `NONCLUSTERED` and doesn't include `age`, SQL Server also has to do a RID Lookup to get the `age`. Again, you can avoid this by making the index `IX_nm2` a `CLUSTERED` index.

```
CREATE clustered index CIX_nm2 on tab2(id1);
```

This would result in a much simpler plan.

[image]